# Print all leaves of a Heap

Tags: c, pointers, heap, nodes

I need to print out all leaves of a heap but i'm not sure if i did it correctly.

For example: Array {A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J}

```
                  A
              B       C
           D    E   F   G
          H I  J
```

So my function should print: H I J F G

Is this correct?

```
void leafdisplay(node *p)
{
    if(p->left ==NULL && p->right ==NULL)
    {
        cout<<p->info;  //  display the node
    }
    else if (p->left==NULL&&p->right!=NULL)
        leafdisplay(p->right);
    else if(p->left!=NULL&&p->right==NULL)
        leafdisplay(p->left);
    else if(p->left!=NULL&&p->right!=NULL)
        leafdisplay(p->left);       
    leafdisplay(p->right);
}
```

Comment: Did you try compiling it yet?

Comment: Also, hint: do you _need_ to check both left and right subtrees _at the same time_?

Comment: Do a depth first search (recurse left then recurse right) and print out every time you have no left and no right. Then you will print out all leaves very quickly :)

Comment: Following up Kotepillar's comment, did you try *running* it ?

Answer (score 0):

Missing `{ }` for the last else if loop

```
else if(p->left!=NULL&&p->right!=NULL)
{
    leafdisplay(p->left);       
    leafdisplay(p->right);
}
```

And you can optimise your code like this

```
void leafdisplay(node *p)
{
  if(p->left ==NULL && p->right ==NULL) 
  {
    cout<<p->info;  //  display the node
  }
  else if (p->left==NULL)
    leafdisplay(p->right); 
  else if(p->right==NULL)
    leafdisplay(p->left); 
  else
  {
    leafdisplay(p->left);       
    leafdisplay(p->right);
  }
}
```